# Primefaces: new p:texteditor edit in plain text mode

Tags: primefaces

I see old p:editor is deprecated and replaced by p:texteditor.
New editor looks nicer but I don't see the "plain text" button mode (rightmost of old p:editor).
Can I have this option in p:texteditor? (p:texteeditor documentation tab in showcase points to old p:editor)

Thanks

Comment: you mean the paste as text or show source?.. maybe you can put a screenshot

Comment: From the JS in the PrimeFaces showscase and github: `/*!
 * Quill Editor v1.0.6
 * https://quilljs.com/
 * Copyright (c) 2014, Jason Chen
 * Copyright (c) 2013, salesforce.com
 */`, so check there if and how it is supported

Comment: I mean editing in source mode. In old editor that is done with the last button in the palette.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible in PrimeFaces 6.0.6 and up, nor 6.1-SNAPSHOT. This is in fact not a PrimeFaces issue or limitation but a limitation in [quilljs](http://quilljs.com), the library the new editor is based upon. So unless they implement it or maybe if PrimeFaces makes a custom patch, it will not be possible in newer PF versions either. See https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/128 on the discussion about it.